# Jboss is not using jboss lib jar commons-lang3-3.0.jar

Tags: ant, jboss, apache-commons-lang

I am using Ant to build my project and deploy it to JBoss. Ant is building using jboss-home/server/default/lib jars. But during deployment it gives error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.apache.commons.lang3 cannot be resolved
StringUtils cannot be resolved
```

I am using commons-lang3-3.1.jar for StringUtils class by following Ant entry:

```
<path id="classpath">
 <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar">  
  <include name="{jboss.home}/server/default/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar" />
```

Comment: 'Unresolved compilation problems' sounds like complilation error. Are you sure there is no error during compilation?

Comment: @arghtype Thanks for reply, yes there are no errors at compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for me it seems like compilation error, but still I can suggest a few things.

1. Try to include 'missing' library into your aplication (for example, place it into web-inf/lib if it is war packaging or use descriptor - *application.xml* or *jboss-app.xml*) and see what will happen.
2. Check if your jboss is actually using the lib: the fact, that jar is located inside jboss directory, does not mean that it will be actually loaded. I don't know what version of jboss you are using, but for jboss as7 it is possible to disable any jar from modules via *module.xml* or via specific server configuration file (like, *standalone.xml*).

Comment: Thank you for answering, The problem was i hadn't included jar file entry for deployment.